Expected Time for Cars to Occupy New Spaces with Probabilistic Movement (in closed form).
I’m working on a problem involving probabilistic movement of cars in a line. There are $N$ cars initially parked in spaces $1$ to $N$, and spaces $N+1$ to $2N$ are empty. Each car can move forward to the next space (i.e., a car in position $i$ can move to position $i+1$) if two conditions are met:

The space in front of the car is empty.
The car's current position is less than $2N$ (i.e., it hasn't reached the end of the available spaces).

Every minute, each eligible car has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of moving forward one space. We have to determine the expected number of minutes before all cars occupy the spaces from $N+1$ to $2N$.

Background and Motivation:
This problem stems from a Monte Carlo simulation I attempted to model, but I’m struggling to find a closed-form solution. The movement of each car is probabilistic, and the dependency of each car’s movement on the car in front makes the process non-trivial.

What I’ve Tried:
I simulated the process to estimate the expected time, but due to the complex dependencies between cars (especially the chain reaction where a car can only move if the car in front has already moved), I haven't been able to generalize the result into a closed-form solution. I’m wondering if there are established techniques, that can help analyze this.

Why this is Interesting:
The problem seems to involve both combinatorics and probability theory, particularly in modeling dependent random walks. I believe the answer could provide insights into processes where agents move probabilistically with constraints based on their neighbors’ positions.

Credit for question :
@leonmozambique533 (source YouTube)

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Have you tried to work it out for small $N$? That could give some clues.

you might have some luck looking up "Totally asymmetric exclusion processes", if you haven't already. a cursory google didn't come up with your exact formulation, but there is plenty of literature about these kind of problems. see eg this paper or wikipedia

Okay, thanks @tkw . I'll go through this topic.

@paw88789 yes but i am not able to generalize it for find any patterns.
